# Format Date of reactive element Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Hey I have simple question but it seems I am missing some vital Information to continue. I have a dataframe that is saved in a reactive function

```
upload_data <- eventReactive(input$upload, {
 read_files(readDirectoryInput(session, 'directory'))

})
```

now I want to format the first column (a date) who's name I don't know through a selectInput dropdown menu:

```
data_tc <- eventReactive(input$datum_formatieren, {
   if (input$datum_format == "dmy") {
   upload_data()[,1] <- dmy(upload_data()[,1]) }
   if (input$datum_format == "ymd") {
     upload_data()[,1] <- ymd(upload_data()[,1]) }
   })
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

My question is what exactly is the output of eventReactive (in this case upload_data()) is it a function?

I tried the suggestion of useR but either nothing happens:

```
output$df <- renderTable({
input$show_data
my_data3 <- upload_data()
  head(my_data3[,1:7])
})
```

or I get the error `incorrect number of dimensions` when I try to convert the date:

```
observeEvent(input$action_format,{
output$message <- renderText({
my_data2 <- data_tc()
my_data2[,1] <- dmy(my_data2[,1])
paste(my_data2[1,1])
})})
```

How can I format the date?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are storing your data any where with `upload_data()`. Try something like: `my_data <- upload_data()` then reference `my_data[,1]` later in your second block of code.

Comment: @useR I edited my post pls see the 2nd part